# How to add a dynamic framework into an internal pod (a static library)?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Our company develops an internal pod that contains all libraries used by all developers here.

Now, I need to add a dynamic framework (more specific: [GoogleCast framework](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_setup)) into this internal pod, and write some wrap up files to use GoogleCast framework in the internal pod.

In podspec, we add the link to GoogleCast framework, and all the dependencies:

```
s.frameworks = 'MediaAccessibility, Accelerate, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, CoreBluetooth, CoreGraphic, CoreText, Foundation, MediaPlayer, MediaToolbox, QuartzCore, SystemConfiguration, UIKit'
s.vendored_frameworks = 'company/frameworks/GoogleCast.framework'
```

`> pod update`

The application can be compiled, but the GoogleCast framework is not found and caused the crash:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast
Referenced from: ...Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices ...
Reason: image not found
```

Any helps?
Thanks

Note: the app supports iOS8+

Comment: Are you linking against the GoogleCast framework inside your pod only, and not inside of the application using your pod?

Comment: In podspec, I link GoogleCast in the variable vendored_frameworks. Actually, it used to work with old version of GoogleCast when GoogleCast was a static framework. Since, it switches to dynamic, we gets this problem. I will edit my question.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be an issue with the way Cocoa pods is linking dynamic library, can you try add use_frameworks! to your podspec to get Cocoa Pods to link the pod as a framework instead of static library?    http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#use_frameworks_bang

Comment: Any reason not to use -  s.dependency  'GoogleCast' ?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, if you have a solution for it, please post it :) thanks you!